# Postgres restore from WAL files without having a basebackup using pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-replication, wal

I have the following situation.

- Have a master/replica setup.
- Somehow the database was dropped and a new database with the same name was created by django.  in this case, will the WAL files of the previous database still be there?
- I have not created a backup using of the previous database using a tool like pg_basebackup, but do have some WAL files in the pg_xlog.

Now, i am trying to do the following:
 - Shutdown the postgres server.
 - Use the recovery.conf file in PGDATA (/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main) directory and entering the following in there:

```
    restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/%f %p'
    recovery_target_time = '2016-01-07 03:00:00'
```

- Startup the postgres server again.

What I see in the log file is:

```
postgres:~/9.3/main/pg_log$ tail -100f postgresql-2016-01-07_170256.log
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-01-07 17:02:55 UTC
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2016-01-06 00:00:00+00
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/0000000A.history’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/0000000A00000000000000CC’: No such file or directory
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/CC000090
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  record with zero length at 0/CC000090
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  redo is not required
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/0000000A00000000000000CC’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/0000000B.history’: No such file or directory
2016-01-07 17:02:56 UTC LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 11
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016/0000000A.history’: No such file or directory
2016-01-07 17:02:57 UTC LOG:  archive recovery complete
2016-01-07 17:02:57 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-01-07 17:02:57 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-01-07 17:02:57 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

My pg_xlog_backup_jan072016 folder has the foll content.:

```
:~/9.3/main/pg_xlog_backup_jan072016$ ls -larth 
total 161M
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  257 Jan  7 15:57 00000007.history
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000CA
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C9
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C8
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C7
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C6
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C5
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C4
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C3
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C2
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  16M Jan  7 15:57 0000000700000000000000C1
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  298 Jan  7 15:57 00000007000000000000005D.00000028.backup
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  214 Jan  7 15:57 00000006.history
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  171 Jan  7 15:57 00000005.history
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  7 16:54 .
drwx------ 18 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  7 17:02 ..
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  7 17:08 archive_status
```

The thing I am trying to figure out is:

- Is it possible to restore from WAL without have a backup from pg_basebackup command? I am just trying to restore from WAL in an existing postgres installation.
- Why does the log say that it cannot find 0000000A.history and 0000000A00000000000000CC files? The folder does not contain any such files.

Can anyone help us with this? 
Thanks. 
Sarthak

Comment: what's your `wal_keep_segments` value? it looks like it was already removed from master before you got it in replica.

Comment: @Dmitry yes that value is the default to 8. My db is not a very high traffic db yet. That means I have about 128 MB of data consider 8 files of 16MB each. Will that mean that I can recover that much data or not?

Comment: I hope you're not still trying to recover this data! But the file `00000007000000000000005D.00000028.backup` looks like a base backup file.